# include in T4 templates only works once

Tags: c#, css, templates, t4

I have an include directive in my T4-Template in C#:

```
<#@ include file="styles.css" #>
```

The text in styles.css is included correctly. But only the first time. If I make changes in the styles.css file and rebuild/rerun the application, the old version is included (as if it comes from a cache or something like that).
The changes in styles.css are only included, if I delete the include directive, build and insert the line after that. Then it works ... until the next changes are made in styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a "solution" for the problem:

The template code is only rebuild when changes in occur in the template itself. Changes in external static files are not recognized. Therefore, the parsing of the template has to be started manually after changes via context menu "Run Custom Tool".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx) for the include directive, there is optional parameter named "once" that defaults to "true".  From the docs:

> Use once="true" to ensure that a template is included only once, even
>   if it’s invoked from more than one other include file.
>
> This feature
>   makes it easy to build up a library of reusable T4 snippets that you
>   can include at will without worrying that some other snippet has
>   already included them.  For example, suppose you have a library of
>   very fine-grained snippets that deal with template processing and C#
>   generation.  In turn, these are used by some more task-specific
>   utilities such as generating exceptions, which you can then use from
>   any more application-specific template. If you draw the dependency
>   graph, you see that some snippets would be included several times. But
>   the once parameter prevents the subsequent inclusions.

My guess is setting this to false would allow your css file to be processed each time.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The "once" option only prevents a multiple include of the same file at different points in the template.

Comment: where are you running the template from?  are you doing design time in Visual Studio or runtime from your application code?

Comment: It's a runtime template with some code in it to fill it with dynamic data from a database.